# {"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Cantact' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to save a contact in my program which is a simple phone book in C# and I'm using linq & Entity Framework & when I want to add or change any data I get a run time error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Contact' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Here's my `insert` (add) code, on the other hand I don't want to add any data in my primary key which is ID and I want to leave it to my SQL Server.

Thank you all for helping me

```
public void Save()
{
    using (var Contex = new Phone_BookEntities1())
    {
        var p = from c in Contex.Cantacts
                where c.Cantact1 == Name
                select new { c.Cantact1, c.Number };

        if (!p.Any())
        {
            Ref_Cantact = new Cantact();
            Ref_Cantact.Cantact1 = Name;
            Ref_Cantact.Number = Num;
            Contex.Cantacts.Add(Ref_Cantact);
            Contex.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public partial class Cantact 
{ 
    public string Cantact1 { get; set; } 
    public string Number { get; set; } 
    public int ID { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: How is your entity configured? Have you defined the identity column to be database-generated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s i haven't done that,i'm not sure what that is

Comment: Can you share the code of the  `Cantact` class?

Comment: Are you using EF with a `.edmx` model, or with a code-first approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/502395/venerik               public partial class Cantact
    {
        public string Cantact1 { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s I Guess it's Code First

Comment: I don't think it is code first. In code first you usually do not have partial classes. Did you have a look at the table in your database? What columns is set to be the identity column? We all seem to expect it is `ID` but you are not setting it explicitly so it might be another, like `Number`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/502395/venerik it's Id i'm sure about that but i added ID after name and number and i'm sure that it's is set az primaray key

Comment: Where did you add it? In the C# class? In the `.edmx` or in the database?  If in the database, did you update the model in the `.edmx` afterwards?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/502395/venerik it's in my database and i'm not sure if i've done it,for updating i should remove my entity and added again or it's not nessasary?!

Comment: @venerik thank you my problem solved

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: @venerik i just updated my my .edmx model,and i also turned on  IDENTITY INSERT i don't know which one was effective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to update my .edmx class in my model

Answer (score 0):

You may do this;

```
    public void Save(string Name, string Num)
    {
          using(var context =  new Phone_BookEntities1())
          {
               var existingContacts = Context.Cantacts.Where( c=>c.Cantact1 == Name); //there can be many contacts with the same name. Use FirstOrDefault and also improve the filtering   criteria
               if(existingContacts.Any())
               {
                    foreach(var contact in existingContacts)
                    {   
                         contact.Number = Num;
                    }
               }else
               {    
                      var Ref_Cantact =  new Cantact(){Cantact1 = Name, Number = Num};
                     context.Cantacts.Add(Ref_Cantact);
               }
               Contex.SaveChanges();
         }
    }
```

Comment: You're linq doesn't have (select) in it

Comment: @MostafaBouzari : It was a copy/paste. Anyway its corrected now. What was the solution to your problem by the way?

Comment: @venerik : op hadn't posted his model when I answered. Now it's clear he has a mismatch between his db design and the model. He also has some confusion about add/update operations. The issue about IDENTITY INSERT should go away automatically once those two issues are corrected. Asking op to deviate from EF and execute sql before adding/updating is not the answer in my opinion,

Comment: @kosalaw  i just updated my my .edmx model,and i also turned on IDENTITY INSERT i don't know which one was effective

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: this will wrap all calls in a transaction, therefore setting identity insert on for the insert statement (Created by EF when calling Add+SaveChanges).

```
if (!p.Any())
            {
                Ref_Cantact = new Cantact();
                Ref_Cantact.Cantact1 = Name;
                Ref_Cantact.Number = Num;
                using(var trans=Contex.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    Contex.Database.ExecuteSqlStatement("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Contact ON;");
                    Contex.Cantacts.Add(Ref_Cantact);
                    Contex.SaveChanges();
                    trans.Commit();
                }
            }
```

EDIT: Another possibility would be setting AutoIncrement (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity) off, using (in your modelbuilder in context class (or whereever)):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Cantacts>().Property(x=>x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```