# I'm having trouble with this linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get some data out and use it in other level. I can't return (c), and I'm looking for a pattern. How can I return that correctly?

```
public string AutoUpdate(string _search)
{
    using (var context = new Phone_BookEntities1())
    {
        var c = from d in context.Cantacts
                where d.Cantact1 == _search
                select d.Cantact1.ToString();
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm... it's spelled `Contact` not `Cantact`

Comment: Not in his domain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645362/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-cantact-when-ident

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Problem is your query is returning `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is the type of `Cantact1`but here since you are converting it to string, it will return `IEnumerable<string>`. But since the return type is `string` you need to return single item. You can use [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
 var c = (from d in context.Cantacts
          where d.Cantact1 == _search
          select d.Cantact1.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or with Lambda syntax:-

```
var c = context.Cantacts.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Cantact1 == _search);
if(c != null)
   return c.Cantact1.ToString();
else
   return String.Empty;  //any default value
```